# Set default value in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need to display 0 for some columns if there is no data coming from DB. So is it possible to define a default value for a column in the colModel so that I don't need to check for empty values and making them zeros in the array.

Comment: Which `formatter` you use for the column?

Answer (score 2):

There is no any direct way to define default value for any column but you can do this by some way.like

using `Custom Formatter`
You can define your own formatter for a particular column. Usually this is a function.In that function you can check for column value if it is null or empty and return some default value.

For Example :

```
<script>
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
colModel: [ 
  ... 
  {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true,  
                                               formatter:currencyFmatter},
  ...
]
...
});

function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   // do something here to check value and return default value
   if(cellvalue == "" || cellvalue == "null")
   return new_format_value
}
</script>
```